# Way to tell if schema is being normalized or denormalized in processStrategy or idAttribute methods

Tags: redux, normalizr

Is it possible to tell if a schema is being used to denormalize data or if it's being used to normalize data from within the `processStrategy` and `idAttribute` methods of the schema definitions?

It would be easy to determine this later but I am curious if it is possible from within these methods. This would allow me to normalize / denormalize using the same schemas rather than creating a new schema for each process, as described in the solution [here](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr/issues/259#issuecomment-312877283).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processStrategy` is only used during normalization.

Otherwise, no.